# GREP how to select double quotes "" but not «»

Tags: adobe-indesign

I need to set up a GREP style in a paragraph style in InDesign.

What I need is to select the quotation marks `“”` and the apostrophe `’` but not the Guillemets `«»`.

I need to select only `“”` and `’` to apply a character style to lower them on the baseline, while `«»` if present, has to remain in the default position.

For now I tried `['"]`, but this one lowers also `«»` that it's not what I want.

Comment: I think this question would be better suited for the [graphic design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work if you type the literal characters between the brackets `[’‘”“]` instead of `['"]`.